# How to load ethereumjs in browser?

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

Because I'm inserting the JS script within a php file, I need to load the `ethereumjs-tx` and `ethereumjs-common` packages from a cdn provider. I found the following packages to include:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ethereumjs-common@latest/dist/index.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ethereumjs-tx@latest/dist/index.min.js
```

My question is: How do I convert the following 2 lines?

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;  
var Common = require('ethereumjs-common').default;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just treat the scripts as any other embedded scripts:

```
<script src= "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ethereumjs-common@latest/dist/index.min.js"></script>

<script src= "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ethereumjs-tx@latest/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```